# Custom PHP Page Using WordPress login

Tags: plugins, login

I created multiple PHP pages linked to WordPress's DB, where I created a specific table to get information from a posted form. I want people to login using their WordPress credentials to access the page where I show the content of this table.

I tried this:

```
//wp-admin

//Setup location of WordPress
$absolute_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path_to_file = explode( 'wp-content', $absolute_path );
$path_to_wp = $path_to_file[0];

//Access WordPress
require_once( $path_to_wp.'/wp-load.php' );
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work? do you have debugging enabled? do you receive errors?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesnt work because i use an if to check if an user of wordpress is logged, if it is show me a custom text and if not show me another text.

Comment: And if im logged or not it is always false

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make it these way:

1) Create Page Template

2) Check if user is logged in

3) if is use $wpdb global var to access database

4) do your stuff with form

it may look like:

```
/**
 * Template Name: User Form 1
 **/
if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
    wp_redirect( home_url() );
    exit;
}

get_header();

    global $wpdb;
    // http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results
    $forms = $wpdb->get_results( 
        "
        SELECT * 
        FROM my_table_name
        "
    );

    foreach ( $forms as $form ) {
        // do something
    }


get_footer();
```

or if you want it to be without template structure use it without `get_header()` or create a `header-forms.php` and use `get_header( 'forms' )`

But if you still thinking to do it outside the theme and templates than wait for someoune to answer properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I dont want to use the page template. I just added a new folder with some php pages with a form(non cms pages)
But in place to make a login page to see a list of record of customer that use this form. I want to use the function of wordpress to check if admin of wordpress is logged and if yes he can access this list.

i included the header and used the function but it doesnt work :/